# dotnet run gives me "*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated"

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am running Ubuntu 64bit linux.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Pop!_OS 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

and

```
dotnet version:  3.0.100
```

I create a folder named "test".

I cd into test.

I then run:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet run
```

The console returns:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

I am not sure what to do to remedy this.

Comment: What version of .net-core are you using? How did you install it? Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated my post with some of the info you requested. As far as how I installed it , it was a few weeks ago and I don't exactly remember but I think it was something like what is described in this article:  https://dev.to/carlos487/installing-dotnet-core-in-ubuntu-1804-7lp

Comment: This seems a known issue, you can track it here https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/8466

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue, as tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/8466).

The work-around for it is running the `.dll` directly, like so:

```
dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/[your-application.dll]
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but it is upvoted, referenced and the bounty expires soon so I'll ok it.